# What arcade motorcycle racing game were Owen Wilson and Jason Sudeikis playing in "Hall Pass"?

Tags: game-identification

I watched *[Hall Pass](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0480687/)*, a comedy film from 2011, and it has a scene where Rick (Owen Wilson) and Fred (Jason Sudeikis) are playing an arcade motorcycle racing game. The arcade cabinet's controls resemble an actual motorcycle, which the player sits on and moves according to the game action. I'm curious to know what game it is.

The game’s HUD shows a speedometer and a “Nitro” indicator. The level they play is “Las Vegas”, and the game displays “Yoo Hoo!” and “Airtime” when the motorcycle does a jump.

Here are some clips and screenshots of the scene:

[image]

[image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That looks to be [Super Bikes 2](https://rawthrills.com/games/super-bikes-2/). There are a lot of matching HUD icons, such as the rectangle on the right and odometer

[image]

Here is a [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/NEl58l4g8AQ?t=252) of the gameplay

Comment: Beat me to it, I was just typing out an answer :)